# Isn't measurement-free quantum error correction uneconomic, i.e. requires too much overhead?

Tags: error-correction, measurement

For certain quantum computing systems, measurement is an operation that takes up >90% of the total quantum error correction time. Measurement-free quantum error correction has been proposed, where instead of measurement we perform qubit reset, which is quick, and we perform the decoding using only quantum resources. So while it's faster, it's also more erroneous, giving us a trade-off.

What I am wondering is: isn't measurement-free QEC completely uneconomical? For every possible syndrome, we have to check using controlled logic gates such as Toffoli that the stabilisers are in a certain state. If we increase code distance, the number of stabiliser permutations we have to check blows up. In papers such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.09804.pdf), this requires a **lot** of ancilla qubits, while in papers such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.13296.pdf), it requires great circuit depth, neither which are really near-term compatible.

So is measurement-free quantum error correction off the table then? Do we have to just tank the fact that measurement is super slow on certain systems, and that real time QEC is a matter of engineering?

Comment: Even if error correction is slow, as long as you are above the threshold for fault tolerance you can still believe that "asymptotically" quantum computers will dominate classical ones for particular algorithms. Practically speaking, the points raised in this question push the quantum advantages farther away

Comment: I suspected so, it seems really inefficient since you are practically taking the classical backend of the decoder and turning it into a noisy quantum circuit. Thanks!